# callbacks and filters in ruby on rails 4.01

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, callback

I am learning rails since last 2-3 months and I have come across some of the concepts of rails. callbacks and filters are the concepts which are very unclear to me. I also read many documentations for the same but i really got confused. some one please clear my this doubts.

Answer (score 3):

**Filters vs Callbacks in Rails**

**Filters:**
Filters are methods that are run before, after or “around” a *controller action*

**before_action**
Before filters are run on requests before the request gets to the controller’s action
eg:validating a user’s authentication before granting them access

**after_action**
After filters are run after the action completes.

**around_action**
Around filters may have logic before and after the action being run.
You can use around filters for exception handling, setup and teardown, and a myriad of other cases.

**Callbacks**:
Callbacks allow you to trigger logic before or after an alteration of an object's state in *model*.

It is possible to write code that will run whenever an Active Record object is created, saved, updated, deleted, validated, or loaded from the database.

**Creating an Object**

```
before_validation
after_validation
before_save
around_save
before_create
around_create
after_create
after_save
after_commit/after_rollback
```

**Updating an Object**

```
before_validation
after_validation
before_save
around_save
before_update
around_update
after_update
after_save
after_commit/after_rollback
```

**Destroying an Object**

```
before_destroy
around_destroy
after_destroy
after_commit/after_rollback
```

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are hooks run when an object is manipulated. For example, if you define

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :do_something

  def so_something
    Rails.logger.error "I do something"
  end
end
```

This will display a message in your log when object a `foo` is created.

Filters are a selection of objects  respecting a condition. For example :

```
Foo.where(:name => "Bar")
```

will only select `foo` object having name `"Bar"`. If you use filters several times, you can declare a specific scope in your model:

```
class Foo
  scope :bar, -> { where(:name => "Bar") }
end

Foo.bar # equivalent to previous line
```

Or more funny:

```
class Foo
  scope :having_name, -> (n) { where(:name => n })
end

Foo.having_name("Bar") # equivalent too !
```